# VSCode creating a .hypothesis/unicode_data/13.0.0/charmap.json.gz file for every project

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-hypothesis

I'm not sure if it's happening because I installed a new library that has that issue, but now every time I run a new project VSCode creates a ".hypothesis/unicode_data/13.0.0/charmap.json.gz" and it's annoying, how can stop it?

I tried looking up the issue on Google but couldn't find much information. There was a post saying it could be related to Pydantic, which I uninstalled, but the issue persists. Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
url = "https:example"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

episode_data = []
for episode in soup.find_all('div', class_='info'):
    episode_number = episode.find('meta')['content']
    title = episode.find('a', itemprop='name').text
    airdate = episode.find('div', class_='airdate').text.strip()
    rating = episode.find('span', class_='ipl-rating-star__rating').text
    total_votes = episode.find('span', class_='ipl-rating-star__total-votes').text
    desc = episode.find('div', class_='item_description').text.strip()
    episode_data.append([episode_number, title, airdate, rating, total_votes, desc])

df = pd.DataFrame(episode_data, columns=['Episode', 'Title', 'Air Date', 'Rating', 'Votes', 'Description'])
```

Comment: so you did `pip install ` of some package ?  please describe clearly...

Comment: yes! I recently installed fastapi and pydantic

Comment: how are you making a "new project" ?  create a new folder and then add files or something else ?

Comment: Yes, I just started a new .ipynb, run the code, and for some reason, vscode creates the "".hypothesis/unicode_data/13.0.0/charmap.json.gz", but it has nothing to do with the code I'm writing

Comment: what are the contents of the file ?

Comment: I can't paste the code in comments but I'm web-scraping an URL using beautifulsoup, standard procedure nothing fancy

Comment: just edit the original question and add the code. then everyone can see it easily.  here is a guide for how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sounds like you need to look at your VS Code extensions, and turn off the one that creates these files. Because "vanilla" VS Code won't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a same [issue](https://github.com/HypothesisWorks/hypothesis/issues/3140) on github.

> Uninstalling pydantic prevents it from happening, re-installing
> pydantic reproduces it.

You can try to upgrade hypothesis to solve it:

```
python -m pip install -U hypothesis
```

Comment: I upgraded hypothesis and it worked. Thanks!